# Telerik asp.net for MVC datepicker format in grid related issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker, telerik-grid, date-format

I have specified date format as dd/mm/yyyy for telerik datepicker. However, it is recognized as mm/dd/yyyy only. For example, if i enter date as 18/10/2012 error on saving record is thrown as date format is not valid as date entered here as 18 is treated as month. I have defined view for date as:

```
@model DateTime?           
@(Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(m => m)
  .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty))      
  .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
  .HtmlAttributes(new { id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty) + "_wrapper" })
  .InputHtmlAttributes(new {style="width:160px;"}))
```

And in model validation for date field is defined as:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date Required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? DATE_CALL { get; set; }
```

Also, in grid has defined column as:

```
col.Bound(r => r.DATE_CALL).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").Title("DATE_CALL").Width(170);
```

So, can't figure out what the error is? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe the error is coming from the SQL. Debug the date format just before the record is saved to DB

Comment: While saving record, since date is not treated as valid format it gets null value for date field and hence throws an error. Format for date field in DB is datetime2(0) in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

use the following to set your date format before saving to the database:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(<yourDate>, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```